Did "Preferred Home Hub" make it into iOS 18 / HomePodOS/tvOS 18 stable release?
I remember seeing reports during the iOS 18 dev and public betas about the ability to choose a "Preferred Home Hub". My searching prior to asking this question reveals lots of articles dated prior to September. To use a single example, reference The Verge's article Apple gives Apple Home users something they’ve been begging for.
In this article they embed media from Reddit, whose image shows a screenshot of the ability to disable Automatic Selection and choose a single Hub to prefer as the network head:

As of just before writing this question I updated my last AppleTV to tvOS 18. It came back from "Not Available" status to "Standby", but my "Home Hubs & Bridges" section appears unchanged without the new options. I do have some third party accessory bridges, but all of my Apple-brand devices should now be fully up to date on iOS 18. Yet, there is no change to my "Home Hubs & Bridges" screen:

I've checked settings everywhere in the Home app as well and I do not believe there is any other section this is relevant. Is there something else I have to do to enable the option to disable automatic Hub selection and choose a Preferred Home Hub?

Hey! Good to see you. Let me know if I can send you any extra details, but this sure looks to be included with my initial updates.

Yes, the initial update for iPadOS 18.0, iOS 18.0 and HomePod 18.0 enabled this feature for my home.
Preferred Home Hubs & Bridges is working for me as I would expect in the home app as seen from my iPad. I have a mini and two original HomePods set up in stereo and I can choose whichever I prefer now instead of doing the power them all off dance and choosing which is powered first.
Automatic selection was enabled for me and once I toggled it off, I could see and chose amongst the three pods.

I'm going to blame^H^H^H^H^H thank you for your post scaring it into working correctly. Because I've restarted my phone and checked the Hubs & Bridges screen a couple times since posting this question, no change.
Came back today, saw your answer and comment, and now it's working. So there probably is some sort of enablement/reconciliation/etc. process, but heck if I know what it is beyond: Time
